# Where can i find CreateProcess error codes' details?

Tags: php, windows, createprocess

I'm running in php the following:

```
$res = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, "C:\\xampp\htdocs\\",null,array('bypass_shell'=>true));
```

Problem is that it gives the following error:

```
Warning: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 3
```

Where can I find out what the error means?

PS: it's on a Windows Server 2007. SP2. User is admin, full acess. PHP is version 5.3.1

Comment: Plus een vir die username.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows, CreateProcess doesn't actually return an error code. Instead you use [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to find more details if CreateProcess fails, then use [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) to turn the error code from GetLastError into a proper description. (The error codes from GetLastError can also be decoded using [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx))

Looking at the source for proc_open(), PHP is actually doing the GetLastError() for you in the event of a failure, and the error code it's logging is the return from GetLastError() rather than from CreateProcess (which returns a BOOL, unlikely to be 3 :) )

Note that proc_open uses this to dump the message:

`php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "CreateProcess failed, error code - %u", dw);`

...so that "-" you've got before the 3 is just a hyphen, not a minus sign. You're therefore getting error code 3, which, according to [that list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) means "The system cannot find the path specified.".

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Ooops, sorry, wasn't paying sufficient attention to the PHP part. I've updated my answer with what's going on from PHP's side, and what that means about decoding your message.